# Size of std::array, std::vector and raw array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Lets we have,

```
std::array <int,5> STDarr;
std::vector <int> VEC(5);
int RAWarr[5];
```

I tried to get size of them as,

```
std::cout << sizeof(STDarr) + sizeof(int) * STDarr.max_size() << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(VEC) + sizeof(int) * VEC.capacity() << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(RAWarr) << std::endl;
```

The outputs are,

```
40
20
40
```

Are these calculations correct? Considering I don't have enough memory for `std::vector` and no way of escaping dynamic allocation, what should I use? If I would know that `std::array`results in lower memory requirement I could change the program to make array static.

Comment: Could you run the same experiment with containers of a different size, for example, 6?

Comment: Changing all 5s to 6s, answer: `48`,`44`,`24` for STDarr,VEC,RAWarr respectively.

Comment: Are you concerned about static overhead size or the extra size per element?

Comment: `std::array` doesn't have overhead. You're counting the `std::array` elements twice, because it's actually stored as an array in the class using the magic of templates. That does mean it's fixed-length, however.

Comment: You are not taking alignment into consideration, you seem to have an 8 byte alignment, if indeed the outputs are ordred correctly.

Comment: @TommyA, sorry I did not understand your question. But I can say that program throws bad_alloc when I use `std::vector`. Its OK with raw array. Since I want safety also, I considered `std::array` but I am not sure with its size.

Comment: The size of `std::array` is `sizeof(STDArr)`.

Comment: It is impossible to know for sure how much memory an instance of `std::vector` occupies, because it does not document its internal workings. It may include a small buffer for small capacities inside of itself, for example. Or it may allocate extra memory for internal purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These numbers are wrong. Moreover, I don't think they represent what you think they represent, either. Let me explain.

First the part about them being wrong. You, unfortunately, don't show the value of `sizeof(int)` so we must derive it. On the system you are using the size of an `int` can be computed as

```
size_t sizeof_int = sizeof(RAWarr) / 5; // => sizeof(int) == 8
```

because this is essentially the definition of `sizeof(T)`: it is the number of bytes between the start of two adjacent objects of type `T` in an array. This happens to be **inconsistent** with the number print for `STDarr`: the class template `std::array<T, n>` is specified to have an array of `n` objects of type `T` embedded into it. Moreover, `std::array<T, n>::max_size()` is a constant expression yielding `n`. That is, we have:

```
40                                               // is identical to
sizeof(STDarr) + sizeof(int) * STDarr.max_size() // is bigger or equal to
sizeof(RAWarr) + sizeof_int * 5                  // is identical to
40             + 40                              // is identical to
80
```

That is `40 >= 80` - a contradication.

Similarily, the second computation is also inconsistent with the third computation: the `std::vector<int>` holds at least `5` elements and the `capacity()` has to be bigger than than the `size()`. Moreover, the `std::vector<int>`'s size is non-zero. That is, the following always has to be true:

```
sizeof(RAWarr) < sizeof(VEC) + sizeof(int) * VEC.capacity()
```

Anyway, all this is pretty much irrelevant to what your actual question seems to be: What is the overhead of representing `n` objects of type `T` using a built-in array of `T`, an `std::array<T, n>`, and an `std::vector<T>`? The answer to this question is:

1. A built-in array `T[n]` uses `sizeof(T) * n`.
2. An `std::array<T, n>` uses the same size as a `T[n]`.
3. A `std::vector<T>(n)` has needs some control data (the size, the capacity, and possibly and possibly an allocator) plus at least 'n * sizeof(T)' bytes to represent its actual data. It may choose to also have a `capacity()` which is bigger than `n`.

In addition to these numbers, actually using any of these data structures may require addition memory:

1. All objects are aligned at an appropriate address. For this there may be additional byte in front of the object.
2. When the object is allocated on the heap, the memory management system my include a couple of bytes in addition to the memory made avaiable. This may be just a word with the size but it may be whatever the allocation mechanism fancies. Also, this memory may live somewhere else than the allocate memory, e.g. in a hash table somewhere.

OK, I hope this provided some insight. However, here comes the **important** message: if `std::vector<T>` isn't capable of holding the amount of data you have there are two situations:

1. You have extremely low memory and most of this discussion is futile because you need entirely different approaches to cope with the few bytes you have. This would be the case if you are working on extremely resource constrained embedded systems.
2. You have too much data an using `T[n]` or `std::array<T, n>` won't be of much help because the overhead we are talking of is typically less than 32 bytes.

Maybe you can describe what you are actually trying to do and why `std::vector<T>` is not an option.

Comment: I was using raw arrays in my code but it was working properly. I though that raw arrays may be the reason so, I tried std::vector to be sure that the problem was raw arrays. However, it throwed bad_alloc. I dont understand; if I have 30,000 ints allocated both to std::vector and raw array, would extra memory usage of std::vector be on the order of bytes more than raw array?

Comment: Typically a `std::vector<T>(n)` allocates `m` with `n <= m` objects of type `T`. The exact `m` isn't specified but in general I would expect it not to be more than `2 * n` except for very small `n` (e.g. the minimum capacity may be 16). That is, there are `m * sizeof(T)` bytes allocated for actual elements. In addition the `std::vector<T>` will need a total of up to four pointers to indicate the start, end, capacity, and the allocator plus the size of the allocator (if it needs any size). How did your code to get 30,000 elements look like?

Comment: The above assumes a size of 8 bytes for int, which is extremely uncommon.  I have not yet encountered a system that has that kind of memory model.  Typically, int will be 4 bytes or fewer which is likely what the original question seems to indicate (i.e. lines up with the outputs from his sizeof()).