# Does a raw array have any advantages over a std::array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, stl, stdarray

According to the accepted answer on [this question about raw arrays vs std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004015/advantages-of-using-arrays-instead-of-stdvector), the advantages of a raw array (back in 2010) were:

> - arrays are slightly more compact: the size is implicit
> - arrays are non-resizable; sometimes this is desireable
> - arrays don't require parsing extra STL headers (compile time)
> - it can be easier to interact with straight-C code with an array (e.g. if C is allocating and C++ is using)
> - fixed-size arrays can be embedded directly into a struct or object, which can improve memory locality and reducing the number of heap allocations needed

To the best of my knowledge, std::array addresses all but the third point.

So unless I desperately need to improve my compile times, is there any reason to use a raw array over a std::array in C++11?

Comment: Can't see any advantage for raw arrays, it's just the other way round (I'm referring to `std::array` BTW not `std::vector`).

Comment: raw arrays can auto size a bit easier.

Comment: @Yakk what do you mean, "auto size"?

Comment: @Barry `int a[] = {1, 2, 3};`

Comment: If you have a function that expects an argument of type pointer/reference to array, then using `std::array` will require [an ugly cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749252/cast-boostarrayfloat-12-for-function-with-argument-const-float-arr12)

Comment: Most compilers support precompiled headers now, so header parse time isn't an issue

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Now that we have std::array what uses are left for C-style arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6111565)

Comment: raw arrays always have advantage in speed and memory

Comment: @SSpoke -1, why do you think `int a[10];` is larger than `std::array<int,10> a`?

Comment: @Yakk one of them is a primitive while the other is wrapped its pretty obvious

Comment: There is such a thing as a zero-cost abstraction. C++ is full of them. [This answer confirms that std::array has the same size as a raw array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778738/2727470).

Comment: @sspoke obvious, but wrong.  `std::array` has no size overhead over an array.  With a reasonable compiler, it has no runtime costs either.  This is C++ not Java, things can exist in code without any runtime existance at all.

Comment: @Yakk I do alot of reverse engineering and I notice anything you use from the library like std::blah it shows up in the strings. try out Hex-Rays decompiler and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @SSpoke (A) on your compiler and (B) the existence of symbols/diagnostic, strings probably created by the exception handling for `.at()`, doesn't have any relevance to the size of the object itself, as you would know if you had analysed this properly. good grief

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it doesn't require you to explicitly specify the size, which makes it easier to initialize it by hand:

```
char const *messages[] =
{
    "Hi",
    "Bye",
    "foo",
    "bar"
};
```

Comment: Note that C++17 adds [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) to the core language and [`std::array` deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides) to the standard library, which allow to not explicitly specify the size *and* the type for the above code snippet.